# CSV and MS-DOS CSV Formats

Tags: csv, export

I have a custom java program which produces a Comma Separated Values (CSV) file. It uses the following output format:

> a,b,c

My users complain that my CSV file is not in the "MS-DOS CSV" format. They provided me with a file in the "MS-DOS CSV" format. I ran diff on my CSV file against their "MS-DOS CSV" file. The two files are identical.

What is the difference between the "MS-DOS CSV" format and the standard CSV format? Is there a tutorial somewhere about how to make the "MS-DOS CSV" format with java?

Comment: Maybe they're referring to line breaks? Some systems like an extra line break at the end of the file? Encoding differences?

Comment: I would bet a lot of money that you didn't use byte comparison but simple cast to ascii comparison. Check those bits and bytes :D

Comment: post the code from the java program

Comment: @McKay - I'm guessing that the difference is in the line returns.

Comment: @Barfieldmv - I haven't tried a diff tool. I'll download one and see what I find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the row delimiter. MS-DOS uses {CR}{LF} or \r\n.