# Check in C# if a CSV file is a DOS-CSV or not

Tags: c#, encoding, csv

How can I check within a **C# program** if a CSV-File is a "DOS-CSV" file or a "normal" CSV file? In other words if an excel sheet was exported to "DOS-CSV" or not.

Comment: Do you mean the difference between a PC CSV file and a UNIX CSV file or MAC CSV?

Comment: Can you explain exactly where the difference is for you? Only line breaks? In that case the [tag:encoding] tag is invalid.

Comment: i guess you are referring to the difference in encoding (If you export as Windows CSV, special charactes will get encoded using the Windows-1252 code page & 437 for DOS_CSV).
Therefore, short of knowing the encoding...you will need to do some guess work. Also read - http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html

Answer (score 2):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098568/csv-and-ms-dos-csv-formats). A heuristic could be to check for the presence of `"\r\n"` in the file.

Comment: Not everyone knows what heuristic means. Clear simple english is always a benefit.

Comment: This is a programmers' forum and technical language is the norm.

Comment: This is a programmer's forum where many users are not English speakers by birth. I'm not clear how your answer benefits users over the simpler alternate: "A way would be to check...". Other will clearly decide. Just trying to be helful.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean that you want to know if the line endings are cr lf (carridge return character and line feed character) as windows or lf as unix. I suggest you download notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ its free, open source and has many goodies such as (under edit) line conversion (the option grayed out is the current detected format).

Comment: I did not downvote, but I could guess that the OP was looking for a way to check programmatically via C#, so your answer doesn't really answer the question

Comment: fair comment, thanks. Yes I was giving a quick way to check and confirm the coding for the file. Of course since the code to do this is open source, thouroughly tested and peer reviewed, its available if there isnt a better solution.